# Is it possible to debug a Swift 4.1 framework in an Objective-C project with XCode 9.3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I have a Swift 4.1 framework that we are implementing in an Objective-C sample app. We are running into issues with certain features not working and would like to know how to debug it without just putting print statements all over the code. The code works find if we implement it inside of a Swift sample app. Our customers need us to proved both though. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have the source code for both then it shouldn't matter if they are mixed.  Generally you will be bringing in the Swift framework using CocoaPods or another similar framework, so the source is available.

Comment: @DavidS. With how our framework is built we can't use CocoaPods to add it to a project. We do this manually by dragging the built framework file into the project we want it in. When I try to step into functions that I am calling from Objective-C it doesn't take me to the swift to debug. How do I "attach" or get it to step into that code?